# Compositing nodes are not showing Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I created an object then clicked on compositing option got 2 nodes there after enable "Use Nodes" option but object was half rendered at that time so I deleted nodes then tried again. 
But now nodes are not showing any more. Is there something I missed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). If you delete nodes manually, you need to add them manually through *Add > Search > Render Layers* and *Composite*

Comment: you can also try with the focus on that screen: press A (to select all nodes), press . (on keypad) to focus on selected nodes (this will focus on nodes if there are some in the window)

Comment: Hi @JachymMichal. I added node manually but it showing me the old one with half render object. Can't I generate new one with proper render?

Comment: Hi. The 'blender-internal-render-engine' tag relates to the Blender Internal render engine (present in blender 2.79) and removed in 2.8. Please don't use it for general rendering questions. Thanks.